# Updating frame of UITableViewCell Subview with AutoLayout

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, subview

I am using auto layout. I have a UIView as a subview to a custom UITableViewCell. In cellForRow I'd like to set the frame of the UIView in cell for Row.

Here's what I have:

```
UIView *bar;
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
               bar = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
               [bar setFrame:CGRectMake(bar.frame.origin.x, 
                                        bar.frame.origin.y, 
                                                        10, 
                                     bar.frame.size.height)];

}
```

If I turn auto layout off, it works. How can I accomplish this using auto layout? I've searched thoroughly and haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using storyboard or the interface builder to create the uiview in those tools, and use constraints to get the desired size of view.

Autolayout can be done programmatically but from what I've seen it's really annoying. The best way to autolayout is using the visual building tools.

check out uitableviewcell xib stackoverflow posts to see how to go about that. Hints for nib:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCellIdentifier"];
```